# Convert List<double> to 0 to 100 normal distribution

Tags: c#

I have a list of doubles ranging from 0 to over 1000.  I want to convert the list to a normal distribution and convert each entry into a number between 0 and 100. I've found a lot about how to calculate means, standard deviations, and random numbers, but nothing about now to convert a list to a normal distribution.

Comment: Could you provide your code please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any code for this. What I have, effectively, is a List<double> ranging from 0 to 1000 (actually, the top number can go higher) and I want to normalize these numbers using a normal distribution between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<double> { ... };
var max = list.Max();
var desiredList = list.Select(p => (p / max) * 100).ToList();
```

Comment: I had implemented this, but the problem is that it's a weighted average. So one number is 1000 and all other numbers are below 500 then the 1000 turns into 100 and the 500 turns into 50. The discrepancy between the 1st and 2nd is just too large, which is why I'm looking to normalize the numbers.

Comment: @user1233136, This depend on your scenario, you can map this numbers with any function, it's your choice, i suggest use logarithm function with optional parameter and coefficient.